# When should I dispose of objects in Xamarin.IOS native?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am building an application that uses a shared project to hold its business logic.

In this shared project each controller has an equivalent.

I use the `ViewDidLoad` method to generate the logic for the controller and attach it to itself like this:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad() {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        _logic = new MyControllerLogic();
        _logic.attach(this);
    }
```

Each logic has its own instance variables etc that should be disposed when they are not used

So when (for example) I navigate backwards from `MyController` to `MyFirstController` or if I replace the application's root view controller , the logic behind the navigated out of/replaced controller has to be disposed.

Where should I do this?

In the android part of the project I did it like this:

```
    protected override void OnPause() {
        base.OnPause();
        if (IsFinishing) {
            _logic?.detach();
            _logic = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an Unwind Segue on the view controller, this is the only reliable way of knowing when a view controller has been dismissed:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Here is a Xamarin example:

https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/ios/general/storyboard/unwind_segue

Comment: Unfortunately while that is quite helpful when navigating between controllers in the same storyboard, I also have a number of storyboards that group together a number of controllers that make sense to be together (I call them modules), so when one module wants to load another, it uses `PresentViewController` to show the next storyboard, and I haven't found a way to unwind from that, and trigger my dispose methods

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is C# based an uses the C# garbage collector.  The most you should do is call is `GC.Collect();`

If you want fine-grained control over memory management, you should use Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: I tried putting GC.Collect(); in every ViewDidAppear method, and that seems to trigger the Dispose() method of all views I have navigated out of, and that seems to work wonderfully, but I have a weird feeling that this could cause a problem, you see I use a lot of extra threads that run in the background and report to the app, but since I allow the user to navigate backwards when they think this is taking too long, the thread will keep on running, preventing GC.Collect() to actually call dispose, at least that is my theory, when I have some time I will test it

Answer (score 0):

For those wandering this is the approach I ended up with (this works for Xamarin but it is adaptable to Swift if one needs to):

I created the following class ,and from now on all my `UIViewController`s will extend this class

```
public abstract class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    protected virtual void Finished() { }

    protected virtual void backPressed() { } //this is just in case I wish to be notified when the user moves back

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated) {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        if (NavigationController != null && NavigationController.ViewControllers.ToList().FirstOrDefault(c => c == this) == null) {
            backPressed();
            Finished();
        }
    }

    public override void DismissViewController(bool animated, [BlockProxy(typeof(AdAction))] Action completionHandler) {
        base.DismissViewController(animated, completionHandler);
        Finished();
    }


    public void Present(string storyboard, bool replace = false, bool animated = true) {
        UIViewController vctl = UIStoryboard.FromName(storyboard, null).InstantiateInitialViewController();
        if (replace) {
            List<UIViewController> old = new List<UIViewController>();
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController is UINavigationController nav) {
                old.AddRange(nav.ViewControllers);
            } else {
                old.Add(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);
            }
            if (animated) {
                UIView.Transition(
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow
                    , 0.25
                    , UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve
                    , () => UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = vctl
                    , () => {
                        old.ForEach(o => (old as BaseViewController)?.Finished());
                    });
            } else {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = vctl;
                old.ForEach(o => (old as BaseViewController)?.Finished());
            }
        } else {
            this.PresentViewController(vctl, animated, null));
        }
    }

    public void AddController(string storyboard, string controller = null, bool animated = true) {
        UIViewController ctl = getController(storyboard, controller);
        this.NavigationController?.PushViewController(ctl, animated);
    }

    public static void ReplaceController(this UINavigationController me, string storyboard, string controller = null, bool animated = true) {
        UIViewController ctl = getController(storyboard, controller);
        UIViewController[] vcl = this.NavigationController?.ViewControllers;
        if (vcl == null) return;
        if (vcl.Length > 0) {
            UIViewController old = vcl[vcl.Length - 1];
            vcl[vcl.Length - 1] = ctl;
            me.SetViewControllers(vcl, animated);
            (old as BaseViewController)?.Finished();
        } else {
            me.PushViewController(ctl, animated);
        }

    }

    private UIViewController getController(string storyboard, string controller = null) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(controller)) {
            return UIStoryboard.FromName(storyboard, null).InstantiateInitialViewController();
        }
        return UIStoryboard.FromName(storyboard, null).InstantiateViewController(controller);
    }

}
```

The only downside is that from now on I have to always use Present to show new Controllers and Add/ReplaceController to show new Controllers inside the current Navigation.

If someone has a better idea please tell me, because I will have to do the above for all types of controllers (UITabBarController etc etc) and that could be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

1. First approach is to write your own navigation service and manage view controllers. And when you use GoBack, you can execute Dispose method for popped ViewController.
2. Second one is use framework like MvvmLight, MvvmCross etc. which provides methods in ViewModel's(your business logic) when should you clean/dispose/unsubscribe and etc.

Code should be like this

```
public class NavigationService
{
   public void NavigateTo(string storyboardName)
   {
      //your logic to present storyboard
   }

   public void GoBack()
  {
     var poppedController = NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
     poppedController.Dispose(); //or your method where you want preclean data;
  }
}
```